# What causes "ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff0a400e22:2251d537:519c37fa:35d4 in state RUN"

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jboss7.x

I have this error in my JBoss AS7 logs, and afterwards all database actions have errors like:

> ISPN000136: Execution error: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Transaction TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction:
>   0:ffff0a400e22:2251d537:519c37fa:35d4 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >
>   is not in a valid state to be invoking cache operations on.
>
> HHH000327: Error performing load command :
>   org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Transaction TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction:
>   0:ffff0a400e22:2251d537:519c37fa:35d4 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >
>   is not in a valid state to be invoking cache operations on.
>
> org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Transaction TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction:
>   0:ffff0a400e22:2251d537:519c37fa:35d4 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >
>   is not in a valid state to be invoking cache operations on.
>
> SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
>
> javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a
>   transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it appears that a mysqldump of the database was the cause. I think it exhausted the connections accepted by the MySQL server, which caused AS7 to drop its database connection, which caused the errors above.

I have used the `--single-transaction` mysqldump option and updating the `max_connections` setting on MySQL to solve the issue.

http://mwibbels.blogspot.com.au/2010/12/mysql-mysqldump-and-dropping-database.html is a good explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. A crontab initiated mysqldump caused this to my server too.